# linux command to lookup total disk and harddrive numbers

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

is there a command in bash that can give you the total number of disk space/harddrive numbers.

I know the [df](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-out-or-learn-harddisk-size-in-linux-or-unix/) command is very helpful but the output is too verbose:

```
    # df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda4       721G  192G  492G  29% /
    tmpfs           129G  112K  129G   1% /dev/shm
    /dev/sda1       194M   92M   93M  50% /boot
    /dev/sdj1       917G  547M  870G   1% /data10
    /dev/sdk1       917G  214G  657G  25% /data11
    /dev/sdl1       917G  200M  871G   1% /data12
    /dev/sdm1       917G  200M  871G   1% /data13
    /dev/sdn1       917G  200M  871G   1% /data14
    /dev/sdo1       917G  200M  871G   1% /data15
    /dev/sdp1       917G   16G  855G   2% /data16
    /dev/sdb1       917G  4.6G  866G   1% /data2
    /dev/sdc1       917G   74G  797G   9% /data3
    /dev/sdd1       917G  200M  871G   1% /data4
    /dev/sde1       917G  200M  871G   1% /data5
    /dev/sdf1       917G  200M  871G   1% /data6
    /dev/sdg1       917G  764G  107G  88% /data7
    /dev/sdh1       917G   51G  820G   6% /data8
    /dev/sdi1       917G   19G  853G   3% /data9
    /dev/sda2       193G   53G  130G  30% /home
    cm_processes    129G   46M  129G   1% /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
```

I basically want '16TB' in the end, is there a command handy or I have to write some program to calculate the total disk based on the output from df.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about:

```
df --total
```

**Hint:** first look to the manual page: `man df`. I find it hard these days to find aspects for a program that have not been implemented by some nice flag. *Linux* people simply seem to know what programmers want/need.

Or if you only want the total:

```
df --total | tail -n 1
```

And if you want to specify it in a special blocksize (like `TB`), you can set the `-B` flag:

```
df --total -BT | tail -n 1
```

And in case you are only interested in the total size (for instance, you wish to use the result in another `bash` program):

```
df --total -BT | tail -n 1 | sed -E 's/total *([^ ]*).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Some versions of `df` do not include `--total` (like mine).

Comment: @Jidder: what is the version of `df`? `df --version`... For 8.21, this works fine.

Comment: `df (GNU coreutils) 5.93` its pretty old ha, just thought i would mention it.

Comment: @Jidder: isn't updating an option?

Comment: Yep it is,i wasn't complaining, i was just adding for people where updating may be a problem. i.e work systems.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using `awk`. This will print header and total lines:

```
df --total -h | awk '!/^\//'
```

- `awk` command will print all lines except those who start with character `/`.
- `df` with `-h` or `--human-readable` print sizes in powers of 1024 (e.g., 1023M).

The result will looks like the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
total           3.9T  1.7T  2.3T  42% -
```

As `Mounted on` field is useless, you can remove it by adding a `sed` to the previous command:

```
$ df --total -h | awk '!/^\//' | sed -E 's/Mounted on|\s-//'
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use%
total           3.9T  1.7T  2.3T  42%
```

Answer (score 3):

CommuSoft's answer is nicer, but here is another solution using awk:

```
df -m | awk '{ SUM += $2} END { print SUM/1024/1024"TB" }'
```

Using the `-m` option make results from `df` be displayed in the same unit (MB). A simple division can translate the result to TB easily.